# Top and bottom composition factors of $M$ are isomorphic

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, finite-groups, modules, noncommutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a field and $N$ a finite group. Let $M$ be a projective indecomposable $kN$-module. Since the algebra $kN$ is symmetric, it follows that the top and bottom composition factors of $M$ are isomorphic. In particular, there is a nonzero endomorphism of
$M$ sending $M$ onto the socle $\operatorname{soc}(M)$.

I cannot see the connection here. How does being symmetric implies composition factors? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Sorry, what's $k$, what's $N$?

Comment: hi! $k$ is a field and $N$ is a group.

Comment: You probably also implicitly assumed that $N$ is finite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For every Frobenius algebra $A$ there is a bijection $\pi$ such that $top(P_i) \cong soc(P_{\pi (i)})$ when $P_i$ denote the indecomposable projective $A$-modules.
Being symmetric implies that $A$ is weakly symmetric (meaning that $\pi$ is the identity). Thus top and socle of every $P_i$ coincide which is what you asked for when I understand your question correct. For proofs and more on this see the book "Frobenius algebras I" in chapter IV. by Skowronski and Yamagata.
When M is an indecomposable projective $A$-module, let $S:=soc(M)$ be the socle of $M$. Then we have a surjective map $M \rightarrow S$ (since top and socle of $M$ coincide) that induces an isomorphism $top(M)=M/rad(M) \rightarrow S$. Thus we have a surjective map $M \rightarrow soc(M)$.

Comment: thank you for your input! question: what is $top(Pi)$? pardon please

Comment: @steven It is the top composition factor, namely $P_i /rad(P_i)$.

Comment: clear now thank you!

Comment: hang on sir. Do we need "the two coincide" to conclude that there is a onto map from $M$ to the socle? what is the connection here? thx!

Comment: helpful! thx you!

Comment: One last question, sir. Can we conclude that socle series and radical series have successive quotients simple in the case of projective indecomposable?